# Sed Command behavior difference wrt argument handling

Tags: linux, sed, parameter

Recently I was working on performing a `sed` operation on a config file.
I found that the `sed` command is behaving differently with the parameter `-ir` vs `-ri` :-

```
[root@node system]# sed -ri 's|(^[[:space:]]+[Kk]ernel.*$)|\1 transparent_hugepage=never|' temp_file
[root@node system]# echo $?
0

[root@node system]# sed -ir 's|(^[[:space:]]+[Kk]ernel.*$)|\1 transparent_hugepage=never|' temp_file
sed: -e expression #1, char 60: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
[root@node system]# echo $?
1
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `-i` option to `sed` takes an option argument, a filename suffix to use for the backup file when editing the input file in place. With GNU `sed`, this option argument is optional, but will obviously be used if supplied.

Using `-ir` tells `sed` that the filename of the backup file should have the original name of the input file suffixed by the character `r`.  Since `-r` is now not used, the back reference in the replacement part of the expression is no longer recognised as a valid, since there is no `\( ... \)` group in the pattern (which is how you capture a part of a pattern with a basic regular expression).

In conclusion, `sed -ri` is not the same as `sed -ir`.

Comment: Yes I checked the system also, Thanks for your help

Comment: n.b. the argument is required on BSD seds